# Uneven upper/lower body

Tags: body-measurements, getting-in-shape

My head appears proportionally large compared to my upper body, and my lower body appears very small/thin compared to my upper body.

I am male around 5'7 and 108 pounds (49 kg). What might be causing my body to be this shape? And what can be done to correct this kind of body shape?

Comment: Is there any chance we can get a picture to indicate how vast the difference is?

Answer (score 1):

Your genes determine your body shape. You can't correct something that's not incorrect, but you can make yourself more aesthetic by adding mass to your lower and upper body in correct proportions. Start lifting weights and eat more. Some people are naturally thin and need to eat more than they actually want to if they are going to add weight.

Comment: But I wasn't in the shape iam now 1 year ago and my age is now 19 I stopped growing tall at 17.Is it that my body has lost weight or my head has grown?

Comment: Could be both I guess, but I don't think the head grows a lot at that age, so it's probably mostly weight loss.